# QM - Shooting photons at a certain point until they hit a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

Given some probability distribution $\rho(x)$ of a particle, say I wanted to check if the particle is located at some point between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$, If I were to continuously shoot photons at that region for a long enough time, will I eventually hit the particle at that point? If so, Is there a way of determining that length of time mathematically? Is this situation analogous to the probability distribution evolving to the delta function centred at the region between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$, over that length of time?

EDIT: I should clarify that I refer to shooting photons just as a measuring method. The main point of my question is that if I kept checking if the particle is located in the specific region between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ for a long enough time period, will I eventually find it there?

Comment: If "some point" is where the particle is located and you send a photons there, then it will be detected right away.

Comment: I am talking about the quantum mechanical case where the position of the particle is not certain but rather corresponds to some probability given by its probability density function rho.

Comment: The particle is ALWAYS somewhere. You either luckily hit it directly or you fire many times at one point and HOPE the particle crosses that point AS you are firing.

Comment: "Given some probability distribution ρ(x) of a particle,"   by definition of probability distribution "will I eventually hit the particle at that point" you should find the particle according to the distribution, Otherwise you have the wrong quantum mechanical probability distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...Given some probability distribution ρ(x) of a particle...I wanted to check if the particle is located at some point between x and x+Δx ...

The distribution ρ(x) represents the probability density of interaction at some location x. Whenever you "look", that's the distribution you should use to estimate the probability to find the particle at a certain location.

As long as you don't find the particle, "looking" has no effect on its wavefunction -and the resulting distribution ρ(x). So you can repeat your measurement and look as many times as you like. ρ(x) will not change, but eventually you will find the particle there, yes, assuming that its state - and ρ(x) - has not changed due to other interactions.

So, the main point is that 1) "looking" won't affect the distribution, as long as you don't find the particle 2) given that there is a probability to find it (and that it does not change due to other interactions), after some time you will find it there, yes.

> Is this situation analogous to the probability distribution evolving to the delta function centred at the region between x and x+Δx, over that length of time?

It is not, since the probability distribution won't evolve to a delta function. The wavefunction of the particle is described by a wave equation (in non-relativistic quantum mechanics the Schrodinger equation), there is no wavefunction collapse as long as the position of the particle is not measured (ie you don't "find" the particle). After finding it, it has a new state, which gives a new probability distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a photon flux $F$ [$ph/cm^2/sec]$ and a photon/particle interaction cross section $Q$ [$cm^2$], the particle will be hit by $F\cdot Q$ photons per second. So the particle will be hit by a photon every $1/(F\cdot Q)$ seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The question needs details/clarity to be actually answered. I suggest therefore some considerations for its improvement, which are too lengthy for comments.

- *Exact form of particle-photon interaction* What happens in such an experiment ultimately depends on the form of the particle-photon interaction. [(non-relatvistic) Hamiltonian for a charged particle in electromagentic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)#Charged_particle_in_an_electromagnetic_field) is
  $$
  H= \frac{1}{2m}\left(-i \hbar\nabla-q\mathbf{A}\right)^2+q\phi
  $$
  If now the vector and the scalar potential belong to a quantized field, we have electron photon interaction. This is still too general to say whether the photons would couple to a particular "part" of a particle or whether, e.g., they would cause its transition to a state with different particle density. The question seems to imply a Hamiltonian like
  $$
  H=-\frac{\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m} + V(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)(a^\dagger + a) + \hbar\omega_0a^\dagger a,
  $$
  where the photons interaction with the charge density only in a specific region of space. Such a Hamiltonian needs a specific experimental design (notably regarding the mode structure of the photon field), which is not explained in the OP.
- *How do we detect the charge density?* Another important point is how and what we really learn from a photon interacting with the charge density. Do we detect photons deflected at a certain angle? Do we count the number of photons reflected, assuming the some of them are absorbed? Something else? Photon being a quantum particle, this is not a trivial matter, and will determine what we eventually observe/find. This is not specified in the OP either.